# no funciona wifi linux mint 18.1 serena

Tags: linux, redes

tengo un problema con el wifi. No me sale ninguna opcion para poder conectarme a una red, solamente por cable usb o el cable de red me permite tener acceso. Uso Linux Mint 18.1 Serena 64-bit
Intente varias cosas pero sin exito.
Se que el problema es por driver que no logro de instalarlo en forma correcta. 
datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

colocando el comando 
"inxi -Fxzc0"   en la parte de network me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Colocando el comando "iwconfig" ; me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si es suficiente informacion con las cosas que brinde, en todo caso si hace falta mas me piden. 
Saludos, espero que alguno me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Maxi Gonzales, Hola amigo, disculpa como pudiste solucionar el problema, tengo exactamente el mismo problema, lo tuve con linux deepin y ahora en linux mint, tengo un notebook hp y no me reconoce la tarjeta de red, llevo muchos dias viendo tutoriales y comentarios de foros pero nada me a funcionado!... Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza los repositorios de tu S.O

Utilizas:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

luego

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Ese es el driver que necesitas, luego reinicias los servicios

```
service networking restart
service network-manager restart
```

Si no funciona simplemente reinicia y listo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ya lo pude solucionar con ayuda en el foro de linux mint.

Comment: @MaxiGonzalez ¿la solución del foro de linux es esta misma? Si no, deberías escribir un respuesta con la solución que seguiste para que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios.